# What is the label directory to scan hard drive for viruses?

Tags: viruses

I just downloaded avg antivirus for my pc with linux on it.  I was wondering how to find the directory label for the hard drive.  I found a page that said that "blkid" was for scanning usb devices.  Is there a label for hard drives?  Any other specific instructions would be nice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Antivirus/Avg), part of Ubuntu Documentation, has some pretty good instructions on using it.  It also tells how to install it.  I hate to plagiarize what was written there, but this is what it has to say:

**Installing AVG Free**

This works for both 32 and 64 bit versions of Ubuntu 10.10 and above.

Download the linux version (.deb file): http://free.avg.com/download.prd-alf
    Double-click on the file which can be found in your download folder then click on the Software Centre Installation button.
    Reboot the PC to initialize AVG. Alternatively you could run

```
sudo /etc/init.d/avgd start
```

**Using AVG Free**

Open a terminal (Applications-Accessories-Terminal). Now update the virus definitions (while connected to the web) with

```
sudo avgupdate
```

To perform a virus check enter

```
sudo avgscan
```

For example you want to scan your USB device:

First type on the terminal:

```
blkid
```

After you do this you will see a list of the devices with some extra information Look for the "UUID" number, also if the device appear to have a "LABEL" then use this last one.

Ok now that you know the "UUID" or "LABEL" if is the case

you can proceed with the following code supposing the "UUID" is AE45, Remember to copy the whole code even if it contains "-" ok now type the following:

```
sudo avgscan /media/AE45
```

Now the scan operations will be performed.